# D3: How to dynamically set the "d" attribute on a path element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, progressdialog

With every other attribute, you can set the value of it using the function(d){} method, however when I try to do that on the "d" attr of a path element, it gives me a huge red invalid value error in the console. My code is below.

**Here's what I'm trying to accomplish (I'm struggling)**
I need to create a progress chart for each data element in my dataset. They all have different max values. 1 chart may need a max value of 4.5, while another may need a max value of 1.0. The way I'm going to try to go about it is have a function called every time a path is created and that function will get passed the max value which will then return the arc variable needed. Any suggestions?

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .endAngle(180 * (Math.PI / 180))
                    .innerRadius(50)
                    .outerRadius(100);

    // Create a variable to append the svg/paths too
    var container = d3.select("#aeGroupMarginSlide");

    // Create an svg element and append a path for each data element
    var svg = container.selectAll(".aeGroupMarginSvg").data(data);
    svg.enter()
        .append("svg")
            .attr({
                "class": "col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 aeGroupMarginSvg",
                "height": 300
            })
        .append("path")  
            .attr({
                "d": function (d) { return arc; },
                "transform": function (d) {
                    var w = $(this).parent().width();
                    var h = $(this).parent().height();
                    return "translate(" + (w / 2) + ", " + (h / 2) + ")"
                },
                "fill": "white"
            })
```

Comment: Try using `arc(d);`. When you do something like `.attr("d", arc)`, the `d` parameter is passed automatically. Within a function block you have to manually pass it.